# Undestanding what causes StoreKit SKErrors

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

It is not clear to me what exactly causes the following errors:

```
SKError.clientInvalid
SKError.paymentInvalid
SKError.paymentNotAllowed
```

I am trying to write error dialogs that are informative and instructive. But since I am not sure what causes the errors, I am not sure how to be instructive.

I guess `.paymentNotAllowed` occurs when parental control is enabled? And `.paymentInvalid` occurs when an error occurs with the payment?

But I have no idea what would cause `.clientInvalid`.

And do I have to handle these cloud service errors for in-app purchases? If so, what would cause them?

```
SKError.cloudServiceRevoked
SKError.cloudServicePermissionDenied
SKError.cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed
```

Comment: Why not present the error localized description? That’s what it’s for.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, thank you. I would still like an understanding so the alert title could be specific, but I guess not strictly necessary. So if you would like to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.